# is it possible to Remove unwating sqlite package from one of Redhat linux docker base image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, redhat-containers

I have redhat linux image for .net core 3.1 **registry.redhat.io/rhel8/dotnet-31-runtime:latest**

In docker file of my application i want to create an image without one if the inner reference package (sqlite)
Is it possible to remove

```
FROM registry.redhat.io/rhel8/dotnet-31-runtime:latest
#RUN yum -y remove sqlite-libs 
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

I have tried RUN yum -y remove sqlite-libs but it didn't work